# Cómo implementar VideoJs con Vue

Tags: vue.js, videojs

He encontrado una [librería genial para videos personalizados con JavaScipt](https://videojs.com/). Quise implementarlo con vue, pues es el framework que estoy utilizando en el momento; y según la [documentación](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-vue.html) (no sé si sea oficial), me dan un ejemplo, pero al momento de implementarlo, me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y sigue bajando con mucho texto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se puede apreciar que sí tengo instalada la dependencia, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Así es el componente de vídeo:

```
<template>

    <div>

        <video ref="videoPlayer" class="video-js" style="max-width: 90%;" preload="auto"></video>

    </div>

</template>

<script>

import videojs from 'video.js';

export default {

    name: "VideoPlayer",
    props: {
        
        options: {

            type: Object,

            default() {

                return {};

            }

        }

    },
    data() {

        return {

            player: null

        }

    },
    mounted() {

        this.player = videojs(this.$refs.videoPlayer, this.options, function onPlayerReady() {

            console.log('onPlayerReady', this);

        })

    },
    beforeDestroy() {

        if (this.player) {

            this.player.dispose()

        }

    }

}
</script>
```

Y así, implemento el vídeo.

```
<template>

    <v-container style="position: relative; width: 100%; background: rgb(89,181,72); background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(89,181,72,1) 0%, rgba(35,130,118,1) 100%);" fluid>

        <vue-particles style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; max-height: 100%;" color="#D3D3D3"></vue-particles>

        <div>
            
            <v-layout class="mr5" justify-center wrap>

                <v-flex class="mr-md-8" xs12 md5>

                    <div style="text-align: justify; position: relative; z-index: 1;">

                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam error sed vero quia, commodi quod obcaecati dignissimos dolore ea culpa expedita enim optio mollitia reiciendis cupiditate natus ipsum at fugiat.
                        Distinctio fuga ex voluptatibus, veniam dolorum qui accusamus, cum in perspiciatis facere nulla quia inventore beatae, ab molestiae tempore quis dignissimos! Cum reprehenderit in sed nesciunt, nihil laboriosam odio inventore.
                        Eveniet quis ipsum sunt perferendis recusandae qui nisi, quo cumque ipsa voluptatem aut deserunt, odio perspiciatis, similique sint optio, nesciunt expedita debitis. Reiciendis recusandae fugiat magni eius, tempore consequatur aspernatur.
                        Ipsum nobis esse vel eum facere, voluptatibus dolorem. Error, provident! Magnam veritatis quisquam cum dolor necessitatibus nihil officiis iste fugit dolores cupiditate vero voluptatibus, perspiciatis? Provident eaque, vero molestiae voluptas!
                        Provident molestias et amet dolores temporibus eos assumenda omnis odio. Libero, sit ea eos quae dignissimos itaque suscipit dolor veritatis assumenda incidunt similique voluptates laborum nisi harum aperiam tempore perferendis.
                        Voluptas et vero ad? A velit officia dolorem placeat, non at odit quae ipsam. Cumque veritatis recusandae ullam eius, reprehenderit nesciunt perspiciatis unde! Aperiam in perferendis non odit! Voluptates, dicta?
                        Totam, voluptas illo sequi sint tempora! Fugit, modi? Cupiditate quaerat tenetur sit consectetur nostrum laudantium commodi, placeat quidem provident fugiat debitis quo iusto ipsum corrupti beatae quibusdam aliquam ducimus, illo?
                        Aliquam et adipisci animi eveniet alias consequatur nesciunt rerum corporis asperiores! Temporibus minima et nisi, rerum, id dolores est animi, delectus fuga odit cumque reprehenderit, aperiam voluptas. Reiciendis, illo, distinctio.
                        Eius assumenda vero, temporibus odio iste est corporis autem minus quo quidem dolor labore deleniti hic at, magnam ex! Ut quo voluptates libero sed quos voluptatibus. Illum vel ab ipsam?
                        Exercitationem temporibus laudantium quae sit doloremque, necessitatibus voluptate consequuntur voluptatem eaque omnis quos, porro saepe modi sunt commodi praesentium odio adipisci eligendi odit, ratione accusamus nemo? Maiores temporibus natus cum?

                    </div>

                </v-flex>

                <v-flex xs12 class="ml-11 mt-5" md5>

                    <!--<iframe style="text-align: justify; position: relative; z-index: 1;" width="80%" height="300" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/sEtpzPFgvkY?controls=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1" class="rounded-lg" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->

                    <VideoPersonalizado :options="videoOptions"/>

                </v-flex>

            </v-layout>

        </div>

    </v-container>

</template>

<script>

    import video from '../assets/videos/modelo.mp4';

    import VideoPersonalizado from '@/components/VideoPersonalizado.vue';

    export default {

        name: 'ComparacionInformacionValtec',
        components: {

            VideoPersonalizado

        },
        data() {
            return {

                videoOptions: {

                    autoplay: false,
                    controls: true,
                    sources: [

                        {

                            src: video,
                            type: "video/mp4"

                        }

                    ]

                }

            };

        }


    };

</script>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me funcione? ¿O si es mejor usarlo como CDN? ¿Y cómo lo podría usar con CDN?

Comment: abri la documentacion.. y abajo dice que te acuerdes de incluir el css.. lo incluiste?

Comment: como lo mandas a llamar en tu componentende `VideoPersonalizado`, en el ejemplo lo crea en el mounted pasando la referencial del video junto con las opciones

Comment: No. No había incluido el CSS. ¿Cómo lo haría? ¿en el index.html, o en el componente?

Comment: Ya pude. Muchas gracias a ambos.

Comment: o sea, el problema era el css??? solamente eso? cierra la pregunta entonces... o pon una respuesta explicando como...